# Telepot - read text of a sent message

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telepot

I use telepot python library with my bot, in python 3.5. I want to read the text of a message that is already in a chat, knowing the id of the telegram chat and the id of the message. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The [telepot](https://pypi.org/project/telepot/) library is a wrapper around the [Telegram Bot HTTP API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) and unfortunately the API doesn't have such method available at the moment. ([see here for full list](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods) of all available methods). Additionally, [telepot is no longer actively maintained.](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot)

Nonetheless, you can directly make requests to the telegram servers (skipping the intermediary HTTP API) by using [mtproto protocol](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) based libraries (such as [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/), [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/), [MadelineProto](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/), etc..) instead.

Here is an example using Telethon to give you an idea:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

API_ID = ...
API_HASH = ' ... '

BOT_TOKEN = ' ... '

client = TelegramClient('bot_session', API_ID, API_HASH).start(bot_token = BOT_TOKEN)

async def main():
    message = await client.get_messages(
        -10000000000, # channel ID
        ids=3 # message ID
    )
    print("MESSAGE:\n---\n")
    print(message.text)

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

```
[user@pc ~]$ python main.py
MESSAGE:
---

test message
```

You can get values for `API_ID` and `API_HASH` by creating an application over [my.telegram.org](https://my.telegram.org) (see [this page](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html) for more detailed instruction)